# Why does this script running su never seem to terminate if I change user inside the script?

Tags: bash, scripts, composer

I have a really simple bash script with 5 commands running under the root user. If I run commands manually one by one everything works - no problem. But as I run it as my-deploy.sh file via command

```
bash /root/custom-scripts/deploy/my-deploy.sh 2>> /var/log/www-deploy/tatrytec.eu.log
```

it seems like endless process. Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run this script as bash command like: bash create-apache-site.sh

cd /var/www/html/tatrytec.eu

git pull

# Change user bacause of composer install warrning
su vlado

composer install  --no-scripts

npm install --production
```

It starts to run and I can see result of git pull in terminal. But then it dies without any error and it is still running. I can stop it via ctrl+Y. I thing something is wrong with that user but as I wrote before if I run commands one by one it works. I dont understand. Can somebody tell me what could be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to run the last lines in your script as the user vlado. There is a clean way to do that:

```
sudo -u vlado  your_command
```

So the last few lines of your script will look like this:

```
sudo -u vlado composer install --no-scripts
sudo -u vlado npm install --production
```

Comment: I change the code to this style. This is nice and clean.

Answer (score 14):

1. <s>`su vlado` will need a password</s> unless run as root.
2. `su vlado` will wait for input
3. commands after `su valdo` are not executed inside `su`, but after exiting `su valdo`

what happen

```
cd /var/www/html/tatrytec.eu  # change dir

git pull # pull git repos

# Change user bacause of composer install warrning
su vlado # either ask password or wait for input

composer install  --no-scripts # if this get executed, you are no longer as vlado
```

---

- the key point is that `su vlado` will fork a new shell, that will ignore (as is) following line in original bash script.
- when copy/pasting you don't have that limitation (as you copy inside vlado's new shell)

I try to explain in more details which user/what happen

```
cd /var/www/html/tatrytec.eu  # ROOT change dir

git pull # ROOT pull git repos

# Change user bacause of composer install warrning
su vlado # VLADO wait for input
new shells as VLADO> sample command
new shells as VALDO> exit

composer install  --no-scripts # ROOT run composer
```

---

proposed correction

as root

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run this script as bash command like: bash create-apache-site.sh

cd /var/www/html/tatrytec.eu

git pull

# Change user bacause of composer install warrning
su vlado  <<EOF

composer install  --no-scripts

npm install --production

EOF
```

where

- `su vlado << EOF` ... `EOF` will feed all lines to `su vlado`

Comment: But if I try to type password it shows the password as plain text and enter does not trigger any action.

Comment: Yes you are right. It behaves like new console and I can write commands in there and they are executed. But how can I run other commands under other user?

Comment: Can you mention su vlado -c 'composer install  --no-scripts' ?

Comment: @Čamo Another option to use `sudo -u vlado composer install --no-scripts`.

Answer (score 10):

Use this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run this script as bash command like: bash create-apache-site.sh

cd /var/www/html/tatrytec.eu

git pull

# Change user bacause of composer install warrning
su vlado -c 'composer install  --no-scripts; npm install --production'
```

The `-c` or `--command` option for `su` allows you to run a command.

Comment: The problem is that I change user because composer install can not run as sudo. It throws warning. The script runs as root user. That is the reason why I need to change user and run commands without sudo.

Comment: Yes now I understand what happened. Its new shell and I can execute commands there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now its working.

Comment: @Čamo Yes, when you run `su` with the `-c` option, it runs the command as the user `vlado` and then it exits after running the specified commands.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `su vlado` needs a password to be typed in.

You could use sudo and make it not need a password for specific commands by modifying /etc/sudoers

Comment: But it should ask me for password. But if I run su vlado as root it does not require password. Are you sure? I could move the script under vlado. But I dont want to do it.

Comment: Didn't notice that you run it as root. The answer from Archemar says that commands after `su vlado` don't get executed inside `su`. I don't know that but if so this could help: `su vlado -c "composer install  --no-scripts"` `su vlado -c "npm install --production"`

Comment: But if I try to type password it shows the password as plain text and enter does not trigger any action. It does not look like it is waiting for password.

Comment: The problem is that composer install throws warning if it runs under the super user. That is the reason why I need to change user from root to vlado.